# Building a profile page that works with vanity URLs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to build a profile page that works with Vanity URLs.

The idea is that `http://domain.com/user123` should load the profile page of `user123`.

This is what I have tried so far in terms of the routing

```
Route::get('/{username}', function()
{
    $user = User::where('username', '=' , $username);

if($user->count()) {
    $user = $user->first();

    return View::make('profilepage')
        ->with('username', $user);
})->where('username', '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.]{3,20}$');
```

Two questions:

1. When I run my test server and try this, I get this error in Line 3 - `ErrorException Undefined variable: username`. I have double checked that the column name matches with that in the table, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing this correctly.
2. Once I manage to route to the correct page, am I correct to say I can access the variable `$user` directly? Or would I need to use `Session::get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The function (closure) must take an argument:

   Route::get('/{username}', function($username) {

   $user = User::where('username', '=' , $username);

   if($user->count()) {
       $user = $user->first();

   ```
   return View::make('profilepage')
       ->with('username', $user);
   ```

   })->where('username', '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.]{3,20}$');
2. You can access it with `Session::get('username')`

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense that it would need an argument. Somehow failed to see that! Very swift response :)

Comment: @Sainath feel free to accept the answer if it worked :)

Comment: It sure did :) Had to wait for the 10 minutes before I could accept it :)